# Total price won't be calculated

Tags: c++, menu

I developed a food menu program about selling sandwich. I don't have any error after compiling the code and the output is normal. But the problem is the total price and the price + gov tax always show 1.50 and 0.09.

These are the following functions I used in my code:

1. Function calPrice()receives the sandwich code and quantity as parameters. This function will return the price for each sandwich and calculate and return the total price.
2. Function addItem()receives the total price as a parameter and will ask the user whether he or she requires additional cheese in the sandwich. Then, the function returns the new price with an additional 6% government tax.
3. Function main() prompts for the sandwich code and quantity from the user.
4. Then, it calls function calPrice() to get the price.
5. Function addItem() calculates the new price after adding cheese and government tax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std ;


double M=8.00;
double C=7.50;
double P=7.00;
double T=6.50;
int calPrice(int code,int quantity)
{
    if(code=='M')
    {
        return(8.00*quantity);
    }
    if(code=='C')
    {
        return(7.50*quantity);
    }
    if(code=='P')
    {
        return(7.00*quantity);
    }
    if(code=='T')
    {
        return(6.50*quantity);
    }
}
int addItem (double total_price)
{
    int quantity;
    int calPrice;
    char answer ='y';'Y';'n';'N';
    double New_price;
    cout << "Additional Cheese? (Y/N) " ;
    cin >> answer ;
    if (answer == 'Y'|| answer == 'y') 
    {           
    cout <<"Add RM1.50 for each"<< endl;
    total_price = calPrice +(1.5*quantity);
    cout <<"Total price :" << total_price <<endl;
    New_price = total_price*0.06 ;
    cout <<"New price + Gov tax (6%) : "<< New_price << endl;
    return (New_price) ;
    } 
    else (answer == 'N'|| answer =='n') ;
    {
    total_price = calPrice ;
    cout <<"Total price :" << total_price <<endl;
    New_price = total_price*0.06 ;
    cout <<"New price + Gov tax (6%) : "<< New_price << endl;
    return (New_price) ;
    }
}
int main ()
{
    char choice = 'M';'C';'P';'T';
    int code , quantity;
    double total_price;
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout <<setw(13)<<"SANDWICH"<<"\t"<<"CODE"<<"\t"<<"PRICE (RM)"<<"\t"<<"ADDITIONAL CHEESE (RM)"<< endl;
    cout <<"     ---------------------------------------------------------"<< endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Meatball"<<setw(7)<<"M"<<setw(14)<< "8.00" << endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Chicken slice"<<setw(7)<<"C"<<setw(14)<<"7.50"<<setw(28)<<"1.50 each"<<endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Pepperoni"<<setw(7)<<"P"<<setw(14)<<"7.00"<<endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Tuna"<<setw(7)<<"T"<<setw(14)<<"6.50"<<endl;
    
    cout << "Choose available sandwich code (M/C/P/T) :";
    cin >> choice;
    while (true)
    {
        if(choice == 'M' || choice == 'C'|| choice == 'P'|| choice == 'T') 
        {
        cout << "Quantity : ";
        cin >> quantity ;break;
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "Choose available sandwich code (M/C/P/T) :";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "Quantity : ";
        cin >> quantity ;break ;
        }
    }
    addItem (total_price);
    return 0 ;
        
}
```

Comment: An `int` will only hold the whole number portion of a `double`.

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings and fix them: https://wandbox.org/permlink/pnskb9nuR8hNbXZP, e.g. what do you expect to happen in `char choice = 'M';'C';'P';'T';`? Do you want to assign 4 values to one variable?

Comment: if(code=='M') --> you are comparing an int (code) to a char ('m')

Comment: @william_ The function `calPrice` is not even called.

Comment: @jabaa was just about to mention that
i have just been reading through the code now seems like way too many mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Below is your code working with a few glitches you will need to fix up ie program works if your input is in capitals ( M, Y not m,y) etc

overall there was a lot of errors in your code

firstly, you never called your calc function so the price was always zero

you also needed to change your ints to doubles when working with money values

your if statement block was comparing an int to a char

You also needed to pass the quantity to your add function

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std ;


double M=8.00;
double C=7.50;
double P=7.00;
double T=6.50;
int calPrice(char code,int quantity)
{
    if(code=='M')
    {
        return(8.00*quantity);
    }
    if(code=='C')
    {
        return(7.50*quantity);
    }
    if(code=='P')
    {
        return(7.00*quantity);
    }
    if(code=='T')
    {
        return(6.50*quantity);
    }
}
void addItem (double total_price,int quanity)
{
    double afterTax;
    double withCheese;
   // double calPrice;
    char answer;
    double New_price;
    cout << "Additional Cheese? (Y/N) " ;
    cin >> answer ;
    
    if (answer == 'Y'|| answer == 'y') 
    {           
    cout <<"Add RM1.50 for each"<< endl;
    withCheese = total_price +(1.5*quanity);
    cout <<"Total price:" << withCheese <<endl;
     afterTax = withCheese*1.06 ;
    cout <<"New price + Gov tax (6%) : "<< afterTax << endl;
    } 
    
    else if (answer == 'N'|| answer =='n') 
    { 
    cout <<"Total price:" << total_price <<endl;
    afterTax = total_price*1.06 ;
    cout <<"New price + Gov tax (6%) : "<< afterTax << endl;
    }
}
int main ()
{
    char choice;
    char code;
     int quantity;
     double price;
    double total_price;
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout <<setw(13)<<"SANDWICH"<<"\t"<<"CODE"<<"\t"<<"PRICE (RM)"<<"\t"<<"ADDITIONAL CHEESE (RM)"<< endl;
    cout <<"     ---------------------------------------------------------"<< endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Meatball"<<setw(7)<<"M"<<setw(14)<< "8.00" << endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Chicken slice"<<setw(7)<<"C"<<setw(14)<<"7.50"<<setw(28)<<"1.50 each"<<endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Pepperoni"<<setw(7)<<"P"<<setw(14)<<"7.00"<<endl;
    cout <<setw(13)<<"Tuna"<<setw(7)<<"T"<<setw(14)<<"6.50"<<endl;
    
    cout << "Choose available sandwich code (M/C/P/T) :";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "Quantity : ";
      cin >> quantity ;
      price = calPrice(choice,quantity);
      
        cout<< "original price: $" << price <<endl;
    addItem(price,quantity);
    return 0 ;
        
}
```

Comment: I corrected just now and i found the problem is still the same. I guess there is a problem with the quantity？

Comment: alright finally i figured it up the problem, the problem has been fixed. Much appreciated.